# How to hide with animation? React + SCSS

Tags: reactjs, animation, sass

I think is just something very simple, but I can't think of anything;

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./header.scss"

export default function(){
    let [curtain, setCurtain] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="header"
             onMouseEnter={() => setCurtain(true)}
             onMouseLeave={() => setCurtain(false)}
        >
            { curtain && <div className="header__curtain__black header__curtain"/> }
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here is SCSS

```
.header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  &__curtain{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    animation: slide_down 0.2s linear;
  }
}

@keyframes slide_down {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Code is super simple and task is super simple too, I want to make a reverse on closing but what do I do ?

Comment: On mouse leave, you instantly unmount the div element without giving time for animation, your options are to add another condition that will work with a timeout or implementing it as a separate component with a state change in `useEffect` callback.

Comment: For further help please make a reproducible example in codesadnbox, read why here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign different class names to the curtain div according to `curtain` state value. I would also suggest to use `transition` property in your css styles instead of keyframe animations.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-dust-gsouf?file=/src/index.js:27-60) is the edited code.

Comment: got it thank you! with keyframes more flexibility ((